# How to delete a subscription in CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I want to delete a specific subscription, but I'm not sure how to obtain the subscription ID.  There are a few options to delete a subscription, all of which requires knowing the subscription ID in advance:

1. [delete(withSubscriptionID:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckdatabase/3003590-delete?changes=_11)

Example:

```swift
let database = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
database.delete(withSubscriptionID: subscription.subscriptionID) { (result, error) in
   // completed 
}
```

2. [fetchAllSubscriptions(completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckdatabase/1449110-fetchallsubscriptions)

Example:

```swift
let database = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
database.fetchAllSubscriptions { subscriptions, error in
    if error == nil {
        if let subscriptions = subscriptions {
            // find the subscription ID of my choice and use the method from #1 to delete
        }
    } else {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

3. [CKModifySubscriptionsOperation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckmodifysubscriptionsoperation#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKModifySubscriptionsOperation/initWithSubscriptionsToSave:subscriptionIDsToDelete:)

Example:

```swift
let operation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: [], subscriptionIDsToDelete: [subscriptionID])
operation.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock =  {
    (modifiedSubscriptions: [CKSubscription]?, deletedSubscriptionIDs: [String]?, error: Error?) -> Void in

    if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        print("Success!")
    }
}
operation.qualityOfService = .utility
privateDatabase.add(operation)
```

For saving and deleting Core Data records, you can use `recordName` to get the `CKRecord` ID, which is easier to save in Core Data:

```swift
let recordID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: recordName)
```

Is there something similar for subscriptions or do I necessarily have to save the subscription ID at the time I create it? It looks like `CKQuerySubscription` doesn't even have `recordName`:

```swift
[<CKQuerySubscription: 0x283a3be40; ; Query Subscription: recordType=Progress, predicate=userId == "_sdfd1cedfea6965asdfdsc58e3d", subscriptionOptions=1, subscriptionID=SDF23BB6B-2C15-4F4D-BE7F-DF234GS, zoneID=(null)>
{
    alertBody -> New Post!
    alertLocalizationKey -> "(null)
    alertLocalizationArgs -> []
    title -> My App
    titleLocalizationKey -> "(null)
    titleLocalizationArgs -> []
    subtitle -> (null)
    subtitleLocalizationKey -> "(null)
    subtitleLocalizationArgs -> []
    alertActionLocalizationKey -> (null)
    alertLaunchImage -> (null)
    soundName -> default
    desiredKeys -> []
    shouldBadge -> NO
    shouldSendContentAvailable -> NO
    shouldSendMutableContent -> NO
    category -> (null)
    collapseIDKey -> (null)

}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you creating the `CKQuerySubscription`s to begin with? You specify an ID for it when you create it and that's how you know what the `subscriptionID` is:

```
let subscriptionWorkspace = CKQuerySubscription(
  recordType: "YourRecordType",
  predicate: ...,
  subscriptionID: "Your-ID-Goes-Here",
  options: [...]
)
```

If you are creating subscriptions to individual `CKRecord`s then you can create a `subscriptionID` like:

```
"YourRecordType|\(recordName)"
```

There are usually better ways of subscribing to entire record types with `predicate` conditions than subscribing to a record at a time, though.

If you want further help, please add more detail about the creation of your `CKQuerySubscription`s.